# Cache environment for DQN

Tags: python, caching, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I need to make a cache environment for my DQN Agent. I need to do network caching, when a file is needed it goes on cache if there is space. If the file is in cache, the agent has a reward. If the file is not in cache and the agent doesn't put it in cache, it has a bad reward.

My environment cache doesn't work, what is the problem? someone can make it work ?

```
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
import pandas as pd


class CacheProva (object):
    def __init__(self, cache_max):
        # Counters
        self.total_count = 0
        self.miss_count = 0
        self.action_space = [0, 1, 2]
        self.df = pd.read_csv('data/size.csv')
        self.df_cache = pd.DataFrame(columns=['movie', 'dim'])

        self.observation = 0 #sarebbe self.cahe_size

        self.n_actions = len(self.action_space)#self.observation + 1
        self.n_features = 0

    def miss_rate(self):
        return self.miss_count / self.total_count

    def step(self, action):
        if self.hasDone():
            raise ValueError("Simulation has finished, use reset() to restart simulation.")

        for index, row in self.df.iterrows():
            self.total_count += 1
            for i, r in self.df_cache.iterrows():
                #self.total_count += 1
                if action == 0:#gia presente nella cache
                    self.df.at[index, row] == self.df_cache.at[i, r]
                    reward = 1
                if action == 1:#mettere nella cache
                    reward = 0
                    self.df_cache.append(self.df.at[index, row])#aggiungere a df_cache
                    self.observation += self.df.at['size']
                elif action == 2:#non è presente e non si mette
                    reward = -1
                    self.miss_count += 1

        return self.observation, reward, self.total_count, self.miss_count
        #self.cureindex
        #if id è in cache size o cache size è vuota, action 0 con reward 1
        #if id non è in cache size e non c'è posto, action 1 la sostituisci reward 0
        # if id non è in cache size e non c'è posto, action 2 non fai nulla reward -1

    def render(self):
        pass
    def reset(self):
        self.total_count = 0
        self.miss_count = 0
        self.observation = 0
        return self.total_count, self.miss_count, self.observation
        #return self.df_cache


    def hasDone(self):
        #return self.cur_index == self.df.shape[0]
        pass



    def display(self):
        print(self.observation)
```

The csv file is a chronology of netflix users, of the film and series watched.

this is my DQN :

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

np.random.seed(1)
tf.random.set_random_seed(1)

# Deep Q Network off-policy
class DeepQNetwork:
    def __init__(
            self,
            n_actions,
            n_features,
            learning_rate=0.01,
            reward_decay=0.9,
            e_greedy=0.9,
            replace_target_iter=300,
            memory_size=500,
            batch_size=32,
            e_greedy_increment=None,
            output_graph=False,
    ):
        self.n_actions = n_actions
        self.n_features = n_features
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.gamma = reward_decay
        self.epsilon_max = e_greedy
        self.replace_target_iter = replace_target_iter
        self.memory_size = memory_size
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.epsilon_increment = e_greedy_increment
        self.epsilon = 0 if e_greedy_increment is not None else self.epsilon_max

        # total learning step
        self.learn_step_counter = 0

        # initialize zero memory [s, a, r, s_]
        self.memory = np.zeros((self.memory_size, n_features * 2 + 2))

        # consist of [target_net, evaluate_net]
        self._build_net()

        t_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='target_net')
        e_params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope='eval_net')

        with tf.variable_scope('hard_replacement'):
            self.target_replace_op = [tf.assign(t, e) for t, e in zip(t_params, e_params)]

        self.sess = tf.Session()

        if output_graph:
            # $ tensorboard --logdir=logs
            tf.summary.FileWriter("logs/", self.sess.graph)

        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        self.cost_his = []

    def _build_net(self):
        # ------------------ all inputs ------------------------
        self.s = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_features], name='s')  # input State
        self.s_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.n_features], name='s_')  # input Next State
        self.r = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, ], name='r')  # input Reward
        self.a = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, ], name='a')  # input Action

        w_initializer, b_initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.3), tf.constant_initializer(0.1)

        # ------------------ build evaluate_net ------------------
        with tf.variable_scope('eval_net'):
            e1 = tf.layers.dense(self.s, 20, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                                 bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='e1')
            self.q_eval = tf.layers.dense(e1, self.n_actions, kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                                          bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='q')

        # ------------------ build target_net ------------------
        with tf.variable_scope('target_net'):
            t1 = tf.layers.dense(self.s_, 20, tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                                 bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t1')
            self.q_next = tf.layers.dense(t1, self.n_actions, kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                                          bias_initializer=b_initializer, name='t2')

        with tf.variable_scope('q_target'):
            q_target = self.r + self.gamma * tf.reduce_max(self.q_next, axis=1, name='Qmax_s_')    # shape=(None, )
            self.q_target = tf.stop_gradient(q_target)
        with tf.variable_scope('q_eval'):
            a_indices = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.shape(self.a)[0], dtype=tf.int32), self.a], axis=1)
            self.q_eval_wrt_a = tf.gather_nd(params=self.q_eval, indices=a_indices)    # shape=(None, )
        with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(self.q_target, self.q_eval_wrt_a, name='TD_error'))
        with tf.variable_scope('train'):
            self._train_op = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss)

    def store_transition(self, s, a, r, s_):
        if not hasattr(self, 'memory_counter'):
            self.memory_counter = 0
        transition = np.hstack((s, [a, r], s_))
        # replace the old memory with new memory
        index = self.memory_counter % self.memory_size
        self.memory[index, :] = transition
        self.memory_counter += 1

    def choose_action(self, observation):
        # to have batch dimension when feed into tf placeholder
        observation = observation[np.newaxis, :]

        if np.random.uniform() < self.epsilon:
            # forward feed the observation and get q value for every actions
            actions_value = self.sess.run(self.q_eval, feed_dict={self.s: observation})
            action = np.argmax(actions_value)
        else:
            action = np.random.randint(0, self.n_actions)
        return action

    def learn(self):
        # check to replace target parameters
        if self.learn_step_counter % self.replace_target_iter == 0:
            self.sess.run(self.target_replace_op)
            print('\ntarget_params_replaced\n')

        # sample batch memory from all memory
        if self.memory_counter > self.memory_size:
            sample_index = np.random.choice(self.memory_size, size=self.batch_size)
        else:
            sample_index = np.random.choice(self.memory_counter, size=self.batch_size)
        batch_memory = self.memory[sample_index, :]

        _, cost = self.sess.run(
            [self._train_op, self.loss],
            feed_dict={
                self.s: batch_memory[:, :self.n_features],
                self.a: batch_memory[:, self.n_features],
                self.r: batch_memory[:, self.n_features + 1],
                self.s_: batch_memory[:, -self.n_features:],
            })

        self.cost_his.append(cost)

        # increasing epsilon
        self.epsilon = self.epsilon + self.epsilon_increment if self.epsilon < self.epsilon_max else self.epsilon_max
        self.learn_step_counter += 1

    def plot_cost(self):
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        plt.plot(np.arange(len(self.cost_his)), self.cost_his)
        plt.ylabel('Cost')
        plt.xlabel('training steps')
        plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DQN = DeepQNetwork(3,4, output_graph=False)
```

Comment: Mark, thanks for the question, but I have to ask, what is the question?

Comment: Yes, sorry, i forgot to write the question. I modified that. The question is: "My environment cache doesn't work, what is the problem? someone can make it work ?"